# Mysql query to get the comma separated value (1,10,15) stored in a column with WHERE Condtion that also has a comma separated Value (15,1,100)

Tags: php, mysql

My Table Look like Below, Please refer Screenshot.[Table Example Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmz46.png)

I want a query to get the "id" when I pass the comma separated values (ex:25,10,3) in WHERE Condition of user_id column.

EX: Select id from table where user_id IN('25,10,3')

When I execute the above query I should get ID's 1 and 2.

I tired with "WHERE IN" and "find_in_set()". But nothing worked out...

Please help me to get this done...

Comment: Use a proper db structure and create another table for linking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: use the concept of primary key and foreign instead of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have Find a Solution for this....

select * from test where user_id REGEXP '(^|,)(25|10|3)(,|$)'

Refer SQL[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74d2ac/3)

Answer (score 0):

Balachander,
find_in_set will work (see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74d2ac/1)), but you should reconsider using proper database structure.

Comment: find_in set works when its select * from test where find_in_set(35,user_id);.... But I need something like this    select * from test where find_in_set(35,100,25,user_id);

Comment: For that you need to fix your table structure. Create a table with id, user_id and put each user_id as separate row.